Change the first segment of the current URL
I have a multilanguage site: en, hu, ro atm. The base URL is example.com/{locale} e.g. example.com/en. The language detection is just checking the locale parameter of the route. I want it to stay this way.
I have a language selector where all locales can be selected and for every page I have link rel alternate for the crawlers to avoid duplicate content problems. So when I visit example.com/en/products/1 the language selector in the layout should have example.com/hu/products/1 and example.com/ro/products/1 as well. I think I should make these URIs in the language middleware and send it to the layout with View::share.
I could build these URIs using the current URI and a simple preg replace or str replace on the first segment, but I guess there is a better way in Laravel. I found that \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::segment(1) is good for getting the first segment and the route pattern is usually /{locale}/sthg/{sthg} appended with query string, but I cannot find a Laravel solution for replacing the first segment. Is there such a thing?

You can use something like request()->route()->setParameter('locale', 'hu') to update en to hu (locale being the name of the URL Parameter {locale}), but I'm still looking into how to then redirect to the adjusted Route without having to do some URL generation nonsense... In the meantime, do you need {locale} in your Route explicitly? You can use Browser Locale then a Cookie/Session variable to set the Locale as a Middleware (or similar) and simply omit the {locale} property (but I do know it's common and sometimes beneficial to have locale in your URL)

Theoretically this should work in a Middleware if you did $request->route()->setParameter('locale', $locale); then return $next($request); in a Middleware, but A) I don't currently have a way to test that and B) I assume you're changing the language via a Controller method (or similar), which doesn't have the Closure $next variable. This is an interesting question though, and feels like it would be a pretty common thing; curious to see what solutions are available/come of this.

@TimLewis Thanks! I need the locale in the URI. Maybe my question is not clear enough, I'll edit it.

if you want to build all language options, and pass them to your views, you can use a view composer:
class LocalesComposer
{
  // inject current request into the ViewComposer
  public function __construct(protected Request $request)
  {}

  public function compose(View $view)
  {
     // filter valid locales, assuming config('app.locales') is an array of all supported locales in this application
     $locales = collect(config('app.locales'))
        ->reject(fn ($locale) => $locale == app()->getLocale());

     $routeName = $this->request->route()->getName();
     $routeParams = $this->request->route()->parameters();

     $languageSelectOptions = $locales->map(function (string $locale) use ($routeName, $routeParams) {
       $routeParams['locale'] = $locale;
       return route($routeName, $routeParams); // return a url for this route
     );

     // pass URLs array to the view
     $view->with('languageSelectOptions', $languageSelectOptions);
  }



assuming you have a controller that handels changes to your locale:
class LocaleController
{
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    // validate locale is a valid one
    
    $prevRoute = Route::getRoutes()->match(Request::create(URL::previous()));
    $prevRouteName = $prevRoute->getName();
    $prevRouteParams = $prevRoute->parameters();

    app()->setLocale($request->locale);
    $currentParams['locale'] = $request->locale;

    // redirect to the same route with the same parameters, except for the locale
    return redirect()->route($prevRouteName, $prevRouteParams);
  }
}


It is not in a controller. I use it in a layout component to generate the hyperlinks for the current page. I could put this code into a middleware maybe. I'll check it later.

I edited the question, maybe it is clearer now.

@inf3rno I made a second answer using a view composer, but the logic is mainly the same. Get a route name and it's parameters, replace the locale parameter, and build a new route with the replaced parameters/
